# Which scopes are available in the default Ubuntu installation?

Tags: application-development, scopes

After I've installed Ubuntu, which scopes are readily available to return results from the Dash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following scopes are available in a default Ubuntu "Saucy Salamander" development image for **desktop** (which will ultimately become the Ubuntu 13.10 release)

## Master scopes

Master scopes can aggregate content from other children scopes. They are provided by the `unity-scope-home` package.

### Default master scopes

[image: Default Ubuntu master scopes as visible at the bottom of the Dash]

These are the visible scopes when first opening the Dash.

1. Home scope
2. Applications scope
3. Files scope
4. Videos scope
5. Music scope
6. Photos scope
7. Social scope

### Other master scopes

These are master scopes that are not visible in the main Dash screen, but which can be revealed as Categories when expanding the Filter Results control in the Dash.

1. Web scope
2. News scope
3. Recipes scope
4. Notes scope
5. Info scope
6. Books scope
7. Reference scope
8. Help scope
9. Boxes scope
10. Calendar scope
11. More suggestions scope
12. Graphics scope
13. Code scope

## Other installed scopes

The following scope packages are available in the Ubuntu development image (Saucy Salamander) as sources results are presented for:

```
unity-scope-audacious - Audacious scope for Unity
unity-scope-calculator - Calculator scope for Unity
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks - Chromium bookmarks scope for Unity
unity-scope-clementine - Clementine scope for Unity
unity-scope-colourlovers - COLOURlovers scope for Unity
unity-scope-devhelp - devhelp scope for Unity
unity-scope-deviantart - deviantART scope for Unity
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks - Firefox bookmarks scope for Unity
unity-scope-gallica - gallica scope for Unity
unity-scope-gdrive - Google Drive scope for Unity
unity-scope-github - GitHub scope for Unity
unity-scope-gmusicbrowser - gmusicbrowser scope for Unity
unity-scope-googlenews - Google News scope for Unity
unity-scope-gourmet - Gourmet Recipe Manager scope for Unity
unity-scope-guayadeque - Guayadeque scope for Unity
unity-scope-home - Home scope that aggregates results from multiple scopes
unity-scope-manpages - Manual pages scope for Unity
unity-scope-musicstores - Ubuntu One music store for unity
unity-scope-musique - Musique scope for Unity
unity-scope-openclipart - OpenClipArt scope for Unity
unity-scope-openweathermap - Openweathermap scope for Unity
unity-scope-soundcloud - SoundCloud scope for Unity
unity-scope-texdoc - Texdoc scope for Unity
unity-scope-tomboy - Tomboy scope for Unity
unity-scope-video-remote - Remote videos engine
unity-scope-virtualbox - VirtualBox scope for Unity
unity-scope-yahoostock - Yahoo! Finance scope for Unity
unity-scope-yelp - Help scope for Unity
unity-scope-zotero - Zotero scope for Unity
unity-scopes-runner - desktop runner for misceallenous scopes
unity-scope-launchpad - Launchpad scope for Unity
unity-scope-sshsearch - SSH search scope for Unity
```

Comment: This doesn't include the facebook one. I think it is `friends-facebook`.