# How to get the list of Dash search plugins (scopes) in command line?

Tags: unity, 13.10, unity-dash, lenses, scopes

I am going to disable all or some of  Dash search plugins (scopes).
I can do it in Dash GUI one by one (see https://askubuntu.com/a/355523/103599) but it seems to me unpractical as there are 56 plugins installed now.
Therefore I am going to disable them from command line like this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

But for this I need to know the names of all scopes, not only amazon, ebay, etc... How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /usr/share/unity/scopes/ -name \*.scope -printf "%P "|sed -es':/:-:g'
```

lists you all locally installed scopes.

With

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "[$(find /usr/share/unity/scopes/ -name \*.scope -printf "'%P',"|sed -es':/:-:g' -e's/,$//')]"
```

you can disable all, so you can just enable the ones you want. You need to have at least `applications-scopes.scope` enabled to use the Dash to manage Scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but about half of scopes are still enabled. For example 'reference-wikipedia.scope' is enabled. I would like to disable all of them.

Comment: It doesn't disable remote Smart Scopes.  I don't know how to get a list of what Smart Scopes are available. Do disable them all you can turn off online results in the Privacy settings.