# Cannot access installed applications from HUD

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I was trying to get rid of dash plugins **within the search**, so I created & copied a list of my scopes and used:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "[$(find /usr/share/unity/scopes/ -name \*.scope -printf "'%P',"|sed -es':/:-:g' -e's/,$//')]"
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390699/how-to-get-the-list-of-dash-search-plugins-scopes-in-command-line) which totally blanked out the search HUD -as in no access to installed apps or files.  However when I try to use

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses enable-scopes "['wherever.scope']"
```

to get indivdual (or all) back I get "no such key enable-scopes". So, what am I not doing right to get singular items (or the the whole thing if need be) back?

Answer (score 0):

Login to Ubuntu and use Ctrl + Alt + F1 to enter TTY. Next, enter user name, password, and run the following command.

Code:

```
unity --reset
```

Wait until the process is complete and your user name appears again. Use Ctrl + Alt + F7 to renter the desktop environment

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008891)

Comment: I just get code:: command not found. Should I be using sudo or something else? Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: **unity --reset**     is the command. type that alone and see

Comment: Nope. It shows "Reset Option is Depricated" I checked, it's been unused since 12.10. (although no one has said anything other than using ccsm which does not help my problem)

Comment: try *dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ & 
unity --reset-icons &disown* as per this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/286349#286349

Comment: That reset the bar, which makes me think I've not asked my question properly (see edit). Sorry if I mislead you or wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried  myself this command

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "[$(find /usr/share/unity/scopes/ -name \*.scope -printf "'%P',"|sed -es':/:-:g' -e's/,$//')]"
```

and removed all shortcuts to application from HUD

then to re-enable it you have to simply run

```
 gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes
```

I got this info from

```
man gsettings
```

[image]